# Timeout exceptions ending my code unexpectedly with JSCH

Tags: java, recursion, networking, timeout, jsch

I'm using jsch to send files. I have this piece of code :

```
public boolean connect()
{ 
    if (_connect()) return true;
    else if (cons_attempts < 3) 
    {
        cons_attempts ++;
        try 
        {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } 
        catch (InterruptedException ex){}
        finally
        {
            connect();
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public boolean _connect()
{
    try 
    {
        session = jsch.getSession(user, host, port);
        session.setTimeout(15000);
        session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking","no");
        
        session.connect();
        Channel channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
        channel.connect(15000);
        sftp = (ChannelSftp) channel;
        return true;
    }
    catch (JSchException ex) 
    {
        MyLogger.log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage());
        return false;
    }
}
```

My code only has problems with timeout exceptions. Before this, I didn't set timeouts to jsch and the log was :

> -- java.net.ConnectException: Connexion terminée par expiration du délai d'attente (Connection timed out)
>
> -- bye

With the timeouts it logs :

> -- timeout: socket is not established
>
> -- bye

The 1st timeout is not really my problem but the frustrating part is that I don't understant why my program exits after only 1 connection attempt.

With all other exceptions I caught so far, the program did attempt 3 times. What am I missing? What is the cause of my code not trying to connect 2 more times?

Thanks

**Edit:**
-Not sure if it will help but the .jar is executed in a .sh which is executed by a cron job.

-Also the server's OS is Debian.

-According to our network guy, our own firewalls do not seem to be the reason of the timeout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you didn't post the full code of the method calling the connect() method, i assumed that you are calling the connect() method which then call the _connect() method. Then if you want the code  to try three attempt then the connect() method should be

```
 public boolean connect(){ 
   int maxAttempt = 3;
   for(int cons_attempts  = 0 ; cons_attempts   < maxAttempt  ; cons_attempts  ++){ 
     if (_connect()) {return true;}
     try 
      {
         Thread.sleep(3000);
      } 
       catch (InterruptedException ex){}
     }
   }
   return false;
 }
```

Comment: I just call my connect() method from my mainish. I don't think the problem is within the code logic, as it works with all kind of exceptions not timeout related. Thanks though

Comment: Okay! but the code above will loop until maxAttempt is reach, which will make the code call the _connect() for a number of maxAttempt if _connect() didn't return true .

Comment: Yes I saw that, but my code already loops 3 times if failing to connect unless the attempt hits a timeout limit (either the one from JSCH or the one from my sshd) in which case my connect() method return false after only one attempt. How would a 'for loop' act different?

Comment: R Bayo. Since you are using the sftp protocol , i think your code need to catch SftpException too! try add another catch clause that will catch SftpException and you will be fine! trust that work for you

Comment: O-m-g you're right. I can't believe I didn't see that I was only catching those. Edit your answer if you want and I'll accept it. Thanks a lot. I'll update when the error occurs again to validate the 3 attempts but I have very little doubt it won't

Comment: Wait actually that's not it. I'm catching the exception just fine and my code goes on

Comment: i checked the javadoc on JSCH!. since it was an exception causing your code to stop unexpectedly. checking the javadoc on JSCH , there are only two type of exception the library throw.   JSchException and SftpException that extend directly from the Exception class. another solution will be to create a catch clause that will catch Exception instead of JSchException or SftpException . hope that will help you